# Bootstrap data-toggle attribute doesn't do anything?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

It's pure black, just as if I would add an attribute that doesn't exist.
Here's the relevant code

```
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



    <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- As I said, the "data-toggle" attribute is black in my code-->
                <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Comanda</a></li>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="magneti">Magneti de fridiger personalizati</a></li>
                    <li><a href="hartie">Obiecte facuted din hartie</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="contact">Contacteaza-ma</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post the rest of your relevant code

Comment: Have you tried loading jQuery before Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child UL should be inside the parent LI..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Comanda</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="magneti">Magneti de fridiger personalizati</a></li>
        <li><a href="hartie">Obiecte facuted din hartie</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact">Contacteaza-ma</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/xlPmE0dRo0

Comment: I tried it and it still doesn't work... I even copied your code completely just to make sure, and "data-toggle" still appears black.

Comment: What do you mean "black"? Are you using some IDE or looking at rendered HTML in the browser?

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. By black I mean what you would see if you would write a random word instead of an available attribute in the code( <p abcdefg="color: white"> </p> ). I'm using notepad++. Nevertheless, I have fixed the problem.